# Как сделать ExceptBy по нескольким свойствам

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс

```
 class Nomenclatura
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Razdel { get; set; }
        public string Proizvoditel { get; set; }

        public string IdTovara { get; set; }
        public string Nazvanie { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

    }
```

Есть два `List<Nomenclatura>.`

```
var list1 = new List<Nomenclatura>();
list1.Add(new Nomenclatura { Id = 1, IdTovara = "3" });

var list2 = new List<Nomenclatura>();
list2.Add(new Nomenclatura { Id = 2, IdTovara = "2" });
list2.Add(new Nomenclatura { Id = 1, IdTovara = "3" });
```

Хочу получить на выходе элементы которые есть в `list2` и нет в `list1`.  Для этого использую `Except`. Всё хорошо но на данный момент у меня есть сравнение только по одному свойству, а мне хочется по нескольким.  Я делал так, но скорость вообще ниочём

```
 var differences = list2.Where(l2 =>
            !list1.Any(l1 => l1.Id == l2.Id&& l1.IdTovara== l2.IdTovara)).ToList();
```

Comment: `Except` работает при помощи метода `Equals` (ну и `GetHashCode`) в нужном классе. Вы можете их переопределить, указав там нужное сравнение.

Comment: используйте Join, для сравнения анонимный класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  internal class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Nomenclatura>
    {
        public bool Equals(Nomenclatura x, Nomenclatura y)
        {
            if (string.Equals(x.IdTovara, y.IdTovara, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)&&
                string.Equals(x.Nazvanie, y.Nazvanie, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)&&
                string.Equals(x.Proizvoditel, y.Proizvoditel, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Nomenclatura obj)
        {
            return obj.IdTovara.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Nazvanie.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Proizvoditel.GetHashCode();
        }

    }
```

А вот использование его

```
var list1 = new List<Nomenclatura>();
list1.Add(new Nomenclatura { Id = 1, IdTovara = "3", Nazvanie = "naz", Proizvoditel = "proiz" });

var list2 = new List<Nomenclatura>();
list2.Add(new Nomenclatura { Id = 1, IdTovara = "2", Nazvanie = "naz", Proizvoditel = "proiz" });
list2.Add(new Nomenclatura { Id = 2, IdTovara = "3", Nazvanie = "naz", Proizvoditel = "proiz" });  
var onlyDelhiResidents = list2.Except(list1, new MyComparer ()).ToList();
```